# Test for which module an object is from rather than which type it is

Tags: python, instance

With `isinstance` we can check whether something is of a certain type, but how can we test whether an object is a class belonging to a certain module?

Example:

```
>>> type(root)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>

>>> isinstance(root, BeautifulSoup)
True
```

How to test whether this object "belongs" to the bs4 package?

Note: When I go over the objects in the soup recursively, it starts as a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object, but at another level they are `bs4.element.Tag` nodes. This is why I want to check for originating from this module rather than a particular type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know the *module* of an object. Is that correct? If so, you will want to check the object's `__module__` attribute:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup.__module__     # module of BeautifulSoup
'bs4'

>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> soup.__module__               # module of a BeautifulSoup object
'bs4'
```

In light of your comment, you may be after something like this:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<b class="boldest">A bold statement.</b>')
>>> tag = soup.b
>>> tag.__module__                # module of a Tag object
'bs4.element'
```

Comment: Nice, but I want to check it of the instance (so in this case, `root.__module__`). Thanks, this is it!

Comment: @PascalvKooten So `root.__module__` is what you are looking for? Or am I still misunderstanding you?

Comment: Indeed, `__module__` is the answer. I can now use `root.__module__` to test whether `root` is an object originating from the `bs4` module.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Thanks for confirming. Perfect. I'm glad this works for you.

Comment: The main reason is that when I loop over the objects in the soup, I sometimes get `bs4.element.Tag`, so I can not test in my function whether the object is a BeautifulSoup object, but I have to check for the module.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Ah, I see. I will add this example to my answer above.